# Dockerfile for eclipse-temurin:17-alpine works with docker build but fails in Azure Pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

I got very strange error today.
I got error from Azure Pipeline which says:

```
##[error]#5 [2/6] RUN apk add --update --no-cache curl &&     curl -l http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/5.17.4/apache-activemq-5.17.4-bin.tar.gz -o activemq.tar.gz &&     tar -xvf activemq.tar.gz &&     mv apache-activemq-5.17.4 /opt/ &&     rm activemq.tar.gz
...
Permission denied
##[error]#5 0.571 ERROR: unable to select packages:
##[error]#5 0.571   curl (no such package):
##[error]#5 0.571     required by: world[curl]
##[error]#5 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c apk add --update --no-cache curl &&     curl -l http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/$ACTIVEMQ_VERSION/$ACTIVEMQ_NAME-bin.tar.gz -o activemq.tar.gz &&     tar -xvf activemq.tar.gz &&     mv $ACTIVEMQ_NAME /opt/ &&     rm activemq.tar.gz" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-alpine

ENV ACTIVEMQ_VERSION 5.17.4
ENV ACTIVEMQ_NAME apache-activemq-$ACTIVEMQ_VERSION

EXPOSE 8161
EXPOSE 61616

RUN apk add --update --no-cache curl && \
    curl -l http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/$ACTIVEMQ_VERSION/$ACTIVEMQ_NAME-bin.tar.gz -o activemq.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf activemq.tar.gz && \
    mv $ACTIVEMQ_NAME /opt/ && \
    rm activemq.tar.gz

WORKDIR /opt/$ACTIVEMQ_NAME
COPY activemq.xml .
COPY jetty.xml .

WORKDIR /opt/$ACTIVEMQ_NAME/bin

ENTRYPOINT ["./activemq","console"]
```

I tested it manually on server, where the agent runs, and for docker build it was working fine:

```
~ docker build -t activemq:latest ./docker/activemq 
...
 => [2/6] RUN apk add --update --no-cache curl &&     curl -l http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/5.17.4/apache-activemq-5.17.4-bin.tar.gz -o activemq.tar.gz &&     tar -xvf  440.9s
 => [3/6] WORKDIR /opt/apache-activemq-5.17.4                                                                                                                                        0.0s 
 => [4/6] COPY activemq.xml .                                                                                                                                                        0.1s 
 => [5/6] COPY jetty.xml .                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => [6/6] WORKDIR /opt/apache-activemq-5.17.4/bin                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                               0.4s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                              0.4s
 => => writing image sha256:778721aca0caa1de9293b88a9c94fc180c5772522e7d5df6680dd5bb79075c36                                                                                         0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/activemq:latest
```

I need to say that I did not changed anything in Dockerfile since last run and it was successful last time.

What can be a problem?

Comment: Have you changed anything in the pipeline or about permission? It seems you are using the self hosted agent, can you try to build it in the MS hosted agent and see if it works?

Comment: No. The pipeline was not used like a month or more. I accidentally ran old pipeline and it failed, and that is why I saw the problem.
I cannot use MS hosted agents because of Security policy of the company.

Comment: Hi @jacobj, In order to better locate the problem, you can segment long commands to find where the problem occurs. In addition, you can set `system.debug` to `true` to see if there will be more debug logs.  You can also compare the difference between the successful log and the failed log to find difference.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `Permission denied` error below:

> ##[error]#5 [2/6] RUN apk add --update --no-cache curl &&     curl -l http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/5.17.4/apache-activemq-5.17.4-bin.tar.gz -o activemq.tar.gz &&     tar -xvf activemq.tar.gz &&     mv apache-activemq-5.17.4 /opt/ &&     rm activemq.tar.gz
> ...
> Permission denied

it's mostly caused by the `agent account` running the pipeline doesn't have permission on the target directory.

You can add `whoami` command in pipeline to confirm the agent account.

To fix the account, you can **reconfigure the agent** with correct account,for example, change to use your local account which can run successfully). Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/linux-agent?view=azure-devops) for agent setup.